# How to size a UIScrollView to fit an unknown amount of text in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have added a scrollview subview in one of my views, but am having trouble getting it's height to accurately fit the content that the scrollview is showing, which is text in the UILabel.  The height needs to be dynamic (i.e. a factor of the text length), because I am instantiating this view for many different text lengths.  Whenever I log `label.frame.bounds` I get (0,0) back.  I have also tried `sizeToFits()` in a few places without much luck.

My goal is to get the scrollview to end when it reaches the last line of text.  Also, I am using only programmatic constraints.

A condensed version of my code is the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let containerView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self

        // This needs to change
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 1000)

        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        label.text = unknownAmountOfText()
        label.backgroundColor = .gray


        containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        containerView.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

SOLUTION found:

```
func heightForLabel(text: String, font: UIFont, lineHeight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.setLineHeight(lineHeight: lineHeight)
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

I found this solution online, that gives me what I need to set the appropriate content size for the scrollView height based on the label's height.  Ideally, I'd be able to determine this without this function, but for now I'm satisfied.

Comment: Why are you doing this programmatically rather than in interface builder? The easiest way to handle this is to use layout constraints, though that can get ugly very quickly in code.

Comment: Why are you putting UILabel into a UIScrollView, and then trying to resize the scroll view to fit the label? Do you want scrolling? If so, why resize the scroll view? If you don't want scrolling, why put the label inside a scroll view?

Comment: I wanted to try a project only with programmatic layouts.  I think in my next project I will use interface builder.  But for now, I am too deep into this project to switch, so I do need to figure this out programatically.

Comment: I do want scrolling.  The text may be larger than what can fit on the screen, so in that case I want users to be able to scroll through the text.  I need to figure out the size of the text at some point to be able to determine the size the scrollview should be.

Comment: OK, still a bit confusing... Is your goal to have a "framed" ScrollView? So if the text is short, and maybe only needs 1/4 of the screen height, you want a Visible Frame 1/4 the height of the screen, around the label? And if the text is a bit more, so it's 3/4 height, you want the visible frame to take up 3/4 of the screen? And if the text would be twice as tall as the screen, then the visible frame is the full screen, and the text scrolls?

Comment: The frame should always be half the screen.  But if the text fits less then half the screen i wouldn't want any scrolling.  But if it's longer then the frame should still be half the screen and the user would be able to scroll through the text.

Comment: OK - scroll views will only scroll if there is enough content to *need* to scroll... You can simply put a UILabel in there, set the constraints properly, and let Auto Layout handle everything for you.

Comment: Is the same true if I'm not using interface builder and doing everything programatically?  I did find a hacky solution that I posted above, which works.  Ideally I'd like ScrollView to just know when to stop scrolling.

Comment: @OliPlunkett - see my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to UIScrollView and its content size is setting your constraints so that the actual *content* defines the contentSize.

For a simple example: say you have a UIScrollView with width: 200 and height: 200. Now you put a UIView inside it, that has width: 100 and height: 400. The view should scroll up and down, but not left-right. You can constrain the view to 100x400, and then "pin" the top, bottom, left and right to the sides of the scroll view, and AutoLayout will "auto-magically" set the scrollview's contentSize.

When you add subviews that can change size - either *explicitly* (code, user interaction) or *implicitly* - if the constraints are set correctly those changes will also "auto-magically" adjust the scrollview's contentSize.

So... here is an example of what you are trying to do:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let label = UILabel()

    let s1 = "1. This is the first line of text in the label. It has words and punctuation, but no embedded line-breaks, so what you see here is normal UILabel word-wrapping."
    var counter = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // turn off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, because we're going to set them
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set background colors, just so we can see the bounding boxes
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)

        // add the label to the scrollView, and the scrollView to the "main" view
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // set top, left, right constraints on scrollView to
        // "main" view + 8.0 padding on each side
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        // set the height constraint on the scrollView to 0.5 * the main view height
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

        // set top, left, right AND bottom constraints on label to
        // scrollView + 8.0 padding on each side
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        // set the width of the label to the width of the scrollView (-16 for 8.0 padding on each side)
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true

        // configure label: Zero lines + Word Wrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)

        // set the text of the label
        label.text = s1

        // ok, we're done... but let's add a button to change the label text, so we
        // can "see the magic" happening
        let b = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(b)
        b.setTitle("Add a Line", for: .normal)
        b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 24.0).isActive = true
        b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func btnTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if let t = label.text {
            counter += 1
            label.text = t + "\n\n\(counter). Another line"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for completely illuminating me to the proper use and magic of scrollviews.  this example was perfect

Comment: one more question... is it necessary to set the `widthAnchor` for the label since you've already set its leading and trailing anchors?

Comment: Yes... the leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors tell the scrollView "these are the edges of your contentSize" ... the width anchor tells the label "don't make yourself any wider than this" ... no height anchor, because you want the label to stretch as tall as it needs to fit the text.

Answer (score 0):

give top,left,right and bottom constraint to label with containerView.
and 
set label.numberOfLines = 0
also ensure that you have given top, left, right and bottom constraint to containerView. this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the auto layout constraints from the interface builder as shown in image .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKgkX.png)

I set the height of UIScrollView as 0.2 of the UIView

Then drag the UIlabel from MainStoryBoard to the view controller.

Add this two lines in viewdidload method.

draggedlabel.numberOfLines = 0

draggedlabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping